# Weird revert with forge test

Tags: solidity

I have a simple contract that emits logs on transfer:

King.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "forge-std/Test.sol";

contract King is Test {
    constructor() public payable {}

    receive() external payable {
        log_named_address("receive() from", msg.sender);
        log_named_uint("value is", msg.value);
    }
}
```

And the test contract, aka King.t.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import {King} from "../src/King.sol";
import "forge-std/Test.sol";

contract KingTest is Test {
    function setUp() public {}

    function testExample() public {
        King king = new King();
        address(king).transfer(1 ether);
    }
}
```

When I run forge test -vvv:

```
%> forge test -vvv
[⠑] Compiling...
[⠘] Compiling 1 files with 0.6.12
[⠢] Compiling 1 files with 0.8.15
[⠰] Solc 0.6.12 finished in 1.32s
[⠘] Solc 0.8.15 finished in 1.34s
Compiler run successful

Running 1 test for test/King.t.sol:KingTest
[FAIL. Reason: Revert] testExample() (gas: 256033)
Logs:
  receive() from: 0xb4c79dab8f259c7aee6e5b2aa729821864227e84

Traces:
  [256033] KingTest::testExample()
    ├─ [214353] → new King@"0xce71…c246"
    │   └─ ← 960 bytes of code
    ├─ [2040] King::fallback{value: 1000000000000000000}()
    │   ├─ emit log_named_address(key: "receive() from", val: KingTest: [0xb4c79dab8f259c7aee6e5b2aa729821864227e84])
    │   └─ ← ()
    └─ ← ()

Test result: FAILED. 0 passed; 1 failed; finished in 446.31µs

Failed tests:
[FAIL. Reason: Revert] testExample() (gas: 256033)

Encountered a total of 1 failing tests, 0 tests succeeded
```

And it failed while accessing `msg.value`, what was wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you used .transfer, which only forwards 2300 gas to the callee, which isnt enough to execute the code contained in your receive function, so it reverted with an out of gas error. Try doing `address(king).call{value: 1 ether}("");`
instead.

Comment: Thanks, I found this link: https://solidity-by-example.org/sending-ether/, both .transfer and .send has a 2300 gas limitation.